# how to solve the .py file in same directory?

Tags: python, import

I am working on a project using python.

I am trying to import the .py file that is in the same parent folder.
This is my simplified project tree

```
My_project
+--run.py
|
+--trn_db.py
```

in `run.py` I did `import trn_db as td` but it has an unresolved import warning.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe a problem with PYTHONPATH

Comment: could you share the exact error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  from . import trn_db as td
```

-should work for python3

Comment: I just tried that but it throws me an Import Error 
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: from trn_db import *

Comment: thank you for your response but I am still getting an error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/facnroll_aws_210215/trnsvr/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    from trn_db import *

Comment: can you plz help me out